# Why does the .NET framework lock dlls?

Tags: c#, .net

Since DLLs get loaded in memory, is there any reason why reference dlls have to be locked by the running process? Is there any way around the locking other than copying the dlls to a temp folder and loading from there?

Comment: Probably because you don't generally want the code you are running getting swapped out from under you (especially since it hasn't been JIT compiled yet).

Comment: Windows and Windows applications have a strong tendency to lock files they use or depend on.

Comment: If you post your problem, you may get a workaround.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: well, this is very debatable. In general, if there is no technical reason to prevent someone from doing something, then it is usually allowed

Comment: @Ehsan: I have say 10 processes running that use the same dll, I want to update the dll without turning off all 10 processes at the same time. If .net didn't lock the dll I could replace the dll, turn off/on each process.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET pretty much any non-Windows OS does that. Are they doing it wrong then? ;)

Comment: @d--b, I agree that it is normally allowed. I'm saying its both a technical issue (running JIT) and a security one (running code you didn't expect to exist).

Comment: @jalf can you think of a non-scripting (compiled) example? Specifically with C# (which does JIT compilation)?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET example of what? It's just what most OS'es do: if you open a file, it opens the file. It doesn't in any way lock it. C# is not doing anything *special* in that regard, it just asks the OS to open the dlls, and the OS does that in whichever way the OS does it. Which on Windows includes locking the files, and on... anything else, involves no locking. Why do you think this behavior would be a *problem*?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: so is it just that it's not allowed because someone decided it shouldn't be allowed? Or is there sometimes a case when the framework goes back to the disk, in some obscure scenario?

Comment: DLLs do NOT get loaded into memory. Not all of the DLL - necessary sections are loaded on demand.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: ok that's what I am asking, is there documentation regarding this? I'm just curious

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a side-effect of the CLR creating a memory-mapped view of an assembly to map it into memory.  Memory mapped files are a low-level feature in Windows, also exposed in .NET 4.0 with the MemoryMappedFile class.  Otherwise a common feature in a demand-paged virtual memory operating system like Windows.

MMFs have lots of desirable properties.  The act of "loading" an assembly becomes very simple and very fast.  Nothing is actually read from the file, it happens in a lazy fashion.  Every byte in the file has a corresponding memory address.  When the CLR tries to read a byte in the assembly metadata or IL for the first time, the processor trips a page fault since the page is not available in RAM.  The operating system handles it by dynamically reading the file content from the disk.  The CLR continues as though nothing happens, it is completely unaware of what happened.

This kind of lazy access is great, you don't pay for what you don't use.  So if you need a single method from a single type in, say, a big assembly like Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll then you only pay for that method.  Your program never actually reads the metadata of other types or the IL of other methods.

There's more.  You don't pay for committing the memory either.  If another process on the machine needs RAM then pages that contain assembly data can simply be discarded.  Since they can just be reloaded from the file.  They don't have to be backed by the paging file, cheapest virtual memory you can buy.

There's more.  The fact that assembly data always needs to be reloadable from the file at any moment in time also means that it can never be correct to allow anybody to modify the file.  Since that would cause the data in RAM to mismatch the data in the file.  And for it to randomly change from the CLR's point of view since it cannot observe the page faults.  So an MMF puts a hard lock on the file, nobody can mess with it.  It is a free anti-malware feature.

There's more.  The lock guarantee also means that the CLR never has to deal with jitted code no longer matching the IL in the assembly.  Something that would be extraordinarily hard to implement since random changes in the assembly are next to impossible to synchronize properly with code execution.  And it would be horribly expensive, method calls could not be simple CALL instructions anymore.  And it isn't limited to code, a delegate object's target method would have to be dynamically resolved.  Very major perf killers.  Otherwise a solved problem, this is why the CLR supports the notion of an AppDomain.  Unloading an appdomain destroys *everything*, code and data.  The underlying technique behind shadow-copying assemblies, as used in high-availability applications like ASP.NET

Comment: Aaaah memory mapped file. That makes sense. Thanks for all the info!