# How to stop .NET Core application from shutting down when it's dll is overwritten?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core

I have a .NET Core application which is invoked from my NodeJS web application (this .NET Core app is migrated from .NET Framework to run it on a Linux server to perform some specific tasks).

So far it works fine, but every time I overwrite the .dll file (to update the app) all running instances of the app are being automatically shut down without any exceptions or anything. As if I would call Environment.Exit(). All work in progress is gone and the calling NodeJS service is receiving just an empty response.

I don't quite understand the need for that as Linux allows to overwrite the file while it's running...
Probably it's working like this to make sure web servers are restarted if their .dlls are updated. But this behavior is undesired in my case and I hope there is a way to disable it.
Tried to google it up but cannot find anything on the matter.

Thanks in advance for any advices :)

Comment: That is normal behavior considering a .NET app. The "application pool" gets recycled when certain things change. Speaking under correction of course, so your initial observation is correct. What we do is have 2 reverse proxies load balanced between the two. We would take the one offline, update the .NET Core code, bring it online and take down the other to update, in that way preserving any/all calls being made to it at the moment. Not entirely sure of your setup or why all WIP would disappear, but that's why we have maintenance windows and fallback :)

Comment: Well, we aren't using .NET Core app as a web server but rather as a standalone console app, that is being invoked from the NodeJS web server, running some work and returning the result. So if it's terminated unexpectedly all the work already is being lost as the calling NodeJS service receives no result and will call the app again next time to start the work from scratch. I'm looking for a way to disable this behavior somehow... I don't need the app to be restarted. I'm happy with the updated version being run for the NEXT time, while this time it could complete the work as is.

Comment: Keep in mind, even on Linux, you can overwrite whatever you want, the service has to also be restarted for the newer changes to take affect, because what is in memory doesnt match the new dll. In all cases, an update to a DLL will initiate a restart (or has to at least), and isn't a behavior you can get rid of. There are ways you could possibly get around it, using ShadowCopy/Assembly, then when it changes, send a notification to wait for the thread to finish and gracefully update. Just speculating from my side, but you might need to wrap your exe in another exe doing update check

Comment: Find background info on why a lock on the assembly is so important in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529924/17034).  No real idea how they did this on Linux, but that the app *must* restart should be obvious from the post.

Comment: Well this is great in Windows or for a _service_ like web server but it's clearly a terrible behavior for a standalone app that's called on demand to perform single task at a time. It definitely will be started again for the next task thus using the new .dll version, there's no need for a forced restart... It seems I'll have to implement some kind of "make a copy before launching -> execute -> delete a copy" approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with writing some kind of shadow copy system.

When my NodeJS app is noticing a new version of the .NET Core app uploaded to the server it renames the folder with the current version ('active') to something like 'old' + timestamp, then renames the new version to 'active'. It is blocking any attempts to launch the app while this renaming process is happening.

This approach helped to completely solve the issue.