# .NET locks all assemblies on runtime, even unused ones

Tags: .net, clr, .net-runtime

I have a .NET 4.7 Solution with several projects, one of them a [ServiceBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase?view=netframework-4.7). I build the Solution, then start the service. Now it seems like the service locks every single DLL in the output folder, even the ones unrelated to the ServiceBase project.
So e.g. I have a standalone Project in the solution with no references to other projects, nor is it referenced by others. Still, I can't build the project when the service is running.

[Here's a helpful explanation of .NET using MMF at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528669/why-does-the-net-framework-lock-dlls). But it doesn't answer why I can't build an unrelated project of the same solution.

Comment: Unless they are being explicitly loaded by code (`Assembly.Load*`, etc.) I would have thought that only those assemblies are loaded that are dependencies. But mind you, that also includes _transitive_ references. You could use a decompiler or other tool to figure out the dependency trees if curious. If updating the "standalone" project inside the common folder, while the other app/service is running, is a common pattern I would suggest not using a common folder for both.

Comment: Thanks, I feared as much. I ran a Dependencies (new Dependency Walker) scan and it also didn't find any dependencies. So that makes the search difficult...
Yes, undoing the common folder would be our last resort.
Thanks for the reply!